# DAX formula to obtain latest month

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a Calendar table and a Transactions table. The Transactions table includes a Date field which is joined to the Date field in the Calendar table.  The Calendar table also includes a Period field (I said "month" in the title, but it could be a fiscal calendar). Now the Transactions table will only include transactions up to a certain date.  For that given date I just need a DAX formula to pick up the corresponding Period from the Calendar table.
It *should* be easy, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the last transaction date and then do a lookup roughly like this.

```
CalendarPeriod =
VAR LastTransDate = LASTDATE(Trans[Date])
RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Calendar[Period], Calendar[Date], LastTransDate)
```

You may need to tweak the definition of the `LastTransDate` variable if, for example, you don't want it to use the filter context when calculating the max.